# MySql Database on Raspberry PI 2 connection via C# Windows Forms Program

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I have just recently started using my Raspberry Pi for a new project.
I have already set up the MySql database (connection with IPadress/phpmyadmin works)
Now I wanted to include the Database in my C# Project, but when I run it I get the cannot connect message from my try/catch. Where can the problem be?
I know this might sound silly, but I am actually stuck.

```
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MyRecipe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            MySqlConnection cnn;
            connetionString = "server='IP-RaspberryPI';database=recipe;uid=recipe;pwd=secret;";
            cnn = new MySqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at my answer im fairly positive that your user does not have the right permissions So you need to conect to your pi via SSH

Comment: Als change your MessageBox error to


MessageBox.Show("Error Message: " + ex.Message);


So you can show us the real error

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is evaluate your exception.

Change the catch statement to something like

`MessageBox.Show("My exception says: " + ex.Message);`

Comment: it says: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure **mysql** to listen for calls on Pi's IP address, or just *localhost*? Assuming that your Pi has a static IP address and not a dynamic one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the string:

```
 "server=192.168.x.x;uid=recipe;" + "pwd=secret;database=recipe"
```

Otherwise it must be the ports on your router open up port 2083 or alternatively it could be that your user has no permissions

**Do this on your raspberry pi SSH**

connect to mysql : mysql -u root -p

CREATE USER 'recipenew'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'recipenew'@'localhost'
WITH GRANT OPTION

**I am almost certain that your user does not have the right permissions**

and then change the string to:

```
  "server=192.168.x.x;uid=recipe;pwd=secret;database=recipe"
```